# Form can't save when adding date format javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Before I add date using javascript, I can save my form. Here is the ajax code

```
function add_computer()
{
  save_method = 'add';
  $('#form')[0].reset();
  $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal 
  $('.modal-title').text('Add'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
}
```

And, I add date using format javascript like the script below

```
function add_computer()
{
  save_method = 'add';
  $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
  var dat = new Date();
  var day = dat.getDate();
  var month = ("0" + (dat.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  var year = dat.getFullYear();

 document.getElementById("tanggal").value = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
  $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal 
  $('.modal-title').text('Add'); // Set Title to Bootstrap modal title
}
```

I cannot save my form, and the error is

> "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

But, the date can show in website.

Why the result become that? and How to solve this?

Comment: I am using oracle database and codeigniter.

Comment: Can you add your html markup ? The id if exists should not give you that error, may be you are running the script before the form loads, It would be more clearer if you add you html as well and indicate where you put your js

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to modify the value of this element -   document.getElementById("tanggal")
Are you sure there is an element with id tanggal ??
Can you share your html, and the full console error, to help you further ?

Comment: <input type="text" id="tanggal" name="TGL_KELUHAN">

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in jQuery:

```
$('#tanggal').val(day+"-"+month+"-"+year);
```

Comment: not yet. Where i put that code? Ang what the function? Thanks for explanation

Comment: Replace  

document.getElementById("tanggal").value = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;

with

$('#tanggal').val(day+"-"+month+"-"+year);

Also make sure that an element with the id of tanggal exists.

Comment: Here's an example of your code working in JSFiddle, you didn't provide any HTML files so I had to add the missing elements as I saw fit.
https://jsfiddle.net/7kf7tdk5/3/

Comment: <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" id="tanggal" name="TGL_KELUHAN">
    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button> here is html code..

Comment: You need to create a save function. I updated JSFiddle to give you an idea of how to do this and get the form data.

https://jsfiddle.net/7kf7tdk5/12/